# why is my program asking for output twice

Tags: java

```
 Scanner sam = new Scanner(System.in);
public class balance {
public double[] returnarray1() {
    System.out.print("Enter account balances seperated by coma:");
    String[] temp = sam.nextLine().split(",");
    double[] bal = new double[temp.length];
    for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++) {
        bal[i] = Double.parseDouble(temp[i]);
    }
    return bal;
}

}
public class interest {
    public double[] returnarray2() {
    balance bl = new balance();
    double[] temp = bl.returnarray1();
    double[] inter = new double[temp.length];
    for(int i=0;i>temp.length;i++) {
        inter[i] = temp[i] * 0.02/12;
        
    }
     return inter;
    
    
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    samiksood ss = new samiksood();
    balance bl = ss.new balance();
    interest it = ss.new interest();
    double[] balance = bl.returnarray1();
    double[] interest = it.returnarray2();
    for(int i =0; i<balance.length;i++) {
    System.out.print("Account "+ i +1);
    System.out.print(balance[i]);
    System.out.println(interest[i]);
    }
    
}
```

when i run it it asks me for output twice which should not happen why is my class repeating?
this program is supposed to seperate a single output into multiple different ones and be placed into a array which is then converted to double the balance is then returned. similarly interest is calculated by preforming calculations on each balance array and returned.they are called into the main method and each array is supposed to be printed.

Comment: The code you've provided is invalid - your first line is outside any class declaration. Please provide a [mcve], properly formatted (the indentation is all over the place at the moment) and ideally following Java naming conventions. The easier it is for others to read, the easier it will be for others to help you. (I'd suggest that using normal capitalization in the text of your question would *also* make it easier to read...)

Comment: (Note that you're calling `returnarray1` twice though - once in `main` and once in `returnarray2`. So it's not really surprising to me that it's printing the prompt twice...)

Comment: i want it to only get the value of the array and not the rest. how can i do that?

Comment: Hint: if the `returnarray2` method needs information that was obtained before, you could pass it in via a parameter... But before fixing it, I would advise you to fix your question, which is still really hard to read.

Comment: @JonSkeet pretty sure the only code missing is that the provided code is wrapped with a class named `samiksood`. at least that creates a runnable example

Comment: @IvoBeckers: It's runnable, but it's *really* hard to read for multiple reasons. I believe it's reasonable to ask questioners to put in the effort to format their code, make it complete, and use regular English capitalization in order to make their question as readable as possible. That makes it more valuable for *future* readers.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're absolutely right about that. I merely told you to help you understand the code

Comment: appologies it's 4 am here and i'm struggling to keep my eyes open will fix later.

Answer (score 2):

You both call `returnarray1` in your `main` and inside `returnarray2` so that's why `returnarray1` is executed twice.

Assuming you want to use the result of the first time in the second time you can change

```
public double[] returnarray2() {
    balance bl = new balance();
    double[] temp = bl.returnarray1();
    double[] inter = new double[temp.length];
    for (int i = 0; i > temp.length; i++) {
        inter[i] = temp[i] * 0.02 / 12;
    }
    return inter;
}
```

to

```
public double[] returnarray2(double[] temp) {
    balance bl = new balance();
    double[] inter = new double[temp.length];
    for (int i = 0; i > temp.length; i++) {
        inter[i] = temp[i] * 0.02 / 12;
    }
    return inter;
}
```

and

```
double[] interest = it.returnarray2();
```

to

```
double[] interest = it.returnarray2(balance);
```

I believe there is also a small bug at this line

```
for (int i = 0; i > temp.length; i++) {
```

because it needs to be

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
```

There's a lot more room for improvement, because a lot of your code is not according to conventions, but it should work at least.

Comment: i want it to only get the value of the array and not the rest. how can i do that?

Comment: @Destroyer2super see  my edit